# S3 redundancy, 3+ availability zone guarantee

Tags: amazon-s3

According to the [S3 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/):

> "Amazon S3 Standard, S3 Standard-Infrequent Access, and S3 Glacier
>   storage classes replicate data across a minimum of three AZs to
>   protect against the loss of one entire AZ. This remains true in
>   Regions where fewer than three AZs are publicly available."

I'm not clear on what this means. Suppose you store your data in a region with fewer than three AZs that are "publicly available." Does that mean that Amazon will store your data in an AZ within that region that is not publicly available, if necessary? Or that it will store your data in an AZ in another region to make up the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 will store your data in an AZ that is not publicly available. The same is also true for DynamoDB, and possibly other services as well.

Source: 
I want to say I heard it at a re:Invent session. I’ll try to find a link to some documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.

Answer (score 1):

> This says even if you have mentioned AZ where publicly available AZs are < 3, Amazon S3 makes sure to replicate your data in a total of at least 3 AZs(including public & non-public).